# Jacobian version of fundamental equation for thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, mathematical-physics

I am intrigued by the Jacobian method of deriving thermodynamic relations. For example, the four Maxwell relations for a single-phase, single-component system, whose fundamental equation is $dE = TdS - pdV$, can be obtained from the Jacobian relation $[TS] = [PV]$, using different choices of independent variables. The relation $[TS] = [PV]$ seems to be profound from a physical point of view, on par with fundamental equation itself.

To demonstrate the use of $[TS] = [PV]$, here is one of the four Maxwell relations, derived using Jacobians with respect independent variables $(T,V)$:

$$\frac{[TS]}{[TV]} = \frac{[PV]}{[TV]}$$ 
leads to 
$$(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_T = (\frac{\partial P}{\partial T})_V$$.

This suggests to me that, mathematically speaking, starting with the differential:

$$ dA = bdB + cdC \tag{1}$$

one should have:

$$ [bB] + [cC] = 0 \tag{2}$$.

That **(2)** should be a consequence of **(1)** seems obvious in light of thermodynamics, but I can't seem to derive it from any of the usual Jacobian identities. I strongly suspect the reason is that **(2)** requires **(1)** to be an exact differential, whereas Jacobian identities must also work under more general circumstances.

My question is simply: what is the most direct derivation of **(2)** from **(1)**?

Comment: what is the definition of the operator [], e.g. [TS]?

Comment: Sorry, the [AB] operator refers to the Jacobian del(A,B)/del(x,y), where x,y are independent variables. The point in thermodynamics is that [TS] = [PV] is true regardless of choice of x,y.

Comment: As an aside, the list of related topics to this question contains an answer (http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/110393/129952) that provides a nice graphical proof to the current question. I wonder if someone can find an elegant alternative proof involving just Jacobian identities (not to take away from the other post!)